# Compose single render helper from two testing library render helpers in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, ecmascript-6, react-testing-library

Cheers. Quick question on using `@testing-library/react` and creating render helpers similar to the below.

```
const renderWithRouter = (
    ui,
    {
        route = '/',
        history = createMemoryHistory({ initialEntries: [route] })
    } = {}
) => {
    const Wrapper = ({ children }) => (
        <Router history={history}>{children}</Router>
    );

    return {
        ...render(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper }),
        history
    };
};

const renderWithRedux = (
    ui,
    {
        initialState = {},
        reducer = {},
        store = createStore(reducer, initialState)
    } = {}
) => {
    const Wrapper = ({ children }) => (
        <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>
    );

    return {
        ...render(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper }),
        store
    };
};
```

How can I change the methods above to be composable like the following?

```
const render = renderWithRouter(renderWithRedux(<Component />,{...}),{...});
```

As far as I understand I can't just get the original UI element from within render. I'm currently stuck in thinking of another alternative. Answers/ideas much appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new method to render with Router and Redux:

```
const renderWithRouterAndRedux = (
    ui,
    {
        route = '/',
        history = createMemoryHistory({ initialEntries: [route] }),
        initialState = {},
        reducer = {},
        store = createStore(reducer, initialState),
    } = {}
) => {
    const Wrapper = ({ children }) => (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Router history={history}>{children}</Router>
        </Provider>
    );

    return {
        ...render(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper }),
        history,
        store,
    };
};
```

If you want to be more flexible I worte a little library that does that: https://github.com/Gpx/render-composer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm currently using the `renderWithRouterAndRedux` version like you described. However I'm looking into a composable option (will look into composer and your library)